# jQuery event listener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div id="mybutton" class="button">label</div>

<script>

      $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.button').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $(this).addClass('green');
        });

        $('.button').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
            $(this).removeClass('green');
        });
      });
</script>
```

nothing happens when i mouseenter #mybutton. why? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. did you include Jquery library.?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/fg7ys/

Comment: FYI what your doing here can be done using CSS alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your script block into Head after jquery script file link.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly alright:

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2dh3/)

I've just added

```
.green{
    color:green;
}
```